# CKEditor <p> tag and removing padding

Tags: php, css, styles, ckeditor

How do i remove p tag margins? I've read a lot of solutions online, and it doesn't seem to work including this 
[a link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/remove-margin-tag-SOLVED-ME)

Comment: adding p{margin:0; padding:0} to contents.css works!.If doesn't check with firebug.

Comment: What have you tried? How is your code? To further add from the above, browsers (if that is what you are testing on) by default add margins and padding to elements, which can be sanitised by using a reset. [[1](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)][[2](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/2.1.3/normalize.css)].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the solution I linked to above worked but my browser (Firefox) was caching the css, so i didn't see it until I tried another browser (Safari)....which is weird.

Comment: FF and Safari have a separate cache, so it's not really that weird that this would happen. The caching issue can be hyper annoying though. It's been discussed many times in relation to ckeditor, for example here: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9781